# Detect facebook page like with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook like button in a MVC view. I want to enable some buttons depending on the status of that like button (Liked or not).

I checked around the net but all the options I found need me to have auth tokens, fb user ids, "signed_request" etc etc. I don't have any of these. I don't wanna put OAuth into the page.

So this page simply has a like button and I just wanna see the state of that button. I was thinking this should probably be possible by looking at the tags in the fb tags generated for the like button using JQuery.

Have any of you guys came across this same problem? Have anyone done this before?

Comment: You can use the facebook javascript SDK to find out whether or not a person has liked your page. This does not require OAuth.

Comment: You can only use signed_requests if you use Page Tab (canvas) app. Otherwise you need to have ùser_likes`permission to tell whether a user likes a Page or not.